# Angular pipe not getting applied inside foreach loop

Tags: foreach, angular5, angular-pipe, angular2-custom-pipes

I am trying to use a pipe inside a foreach loop in my angular component.
My array is populated and so is each item of the array when I debug it

```
   console.log(this.blog);
    this.relatedLinks = this.blog.related;
     this.relatedLinks.forEach(function (link) {
        this.newlink = this.removeSpace.transform(link);
        this.relatedBlogList = this.Blogs.filter(blog => blog.title === this.newlink);
        });
  },
```

But while applying the pipe I get the following error:
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeSpace' of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I think `this` is not accessible inside the `foreach`. Try this and post back with progress.

```
console.log(this.blog);
    this.relatedLinks = this.blog.related;
    let self = this;
     this.relatedLinks.forEach(function (link) {
        this.newlink = self.removeSpace.transform(link);
        this.relatedBlogList = this.Blogs.filter(blog => blog.title === this.newlink);
        });
  },
```